# How to fill up rows with first and last day into a sequence of days?

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have this table:

```
a <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "A first day", "A last day", "B first day", "B last day", "A first day", "A last day", 3, 5, 10, 14, 2, 5), ncol = 3))
colnames(a) = c("Patient", "Treatment", "Day")
```

Which looks like this:

| Patient | Treatment | Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A first day | 3 |
| 1 | A last day | 5 |
| 1 | B first day | 10 |
| 1 | B last day | 14 |
| 2 | A first day | 2 |
| 2 | A last day | 5 |

How can I transform this so that each day from the first to the last gets its own row, so that the table looks like this?

| Patient | Treatment | Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 3 |
| 1 | A | 4 |
| 1 | A | 5 |
| 1 | B | 10 |
| 1 | B | 11 |
| 1 | B | 12 |
| 1 | B | 13 |
| 1 | B | 14 |
| 2 | A | 2 |
| 2 | A | 3 |
| 2 | A | 4 |
| 2 | A | 5 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `sub` to get rid of the extra text. Then split `by` the ID variables which are `1:2` in your case and `cbind` `1`st row of the data frame minus the day variable `-3`, and use `` `:` `` in a `do.call` to get the sequences, finally `rbind` everything. I added some extra columns to demonstrate they are preserved.

```
a$Treatment <- sub('\\s.*', '', a$Treatment)
by(a, a[1:2], \(x) cbind(x[1, -3], Day=do.call(`:`, as.list(as.integer(sort(x[[3]])))), row.names=NULL)) |> 
  do.call(what=rbind)
#    Patient Treatment Sex   X Day
# 1        1         A   m 0.5   3
# 2        1         A   m 0.5   4
# 3        1         A   m 0.5   5
# 4        2         A   f 0.4   2
# 5        2         A   f 0.4   3
# 6        2         A   f 0.4   4
# 7        2         A   f 0.4   5
# 8        1         B   f 0.3  10
# 9        1         B   f 0.3  11
# 10       1         B   f 0.3  12
# 11       1         B   f 0.3  13
# 12       1         B   f 0.3  14
```

---

*Data:*

```
a <- structure(list(Patient = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Treatment = c("A first day", 
"A last day", "B first day", "B last day", "A first day", "A last day"
), Day = c(3L, 5L, 10L, 14L, 2L, 5L), Sex = c("m", "m", "f", 
"f", "f", "f"), X = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 4):

We need to create unique treatment group per patient, therefore we need to get rid of the "first day" and "last day" string in the column. Then `group_by` the `Patient` and `Treatment` columns to create unique group, and use `reframe` to generate a new sequence of `Day` based on the `min` and `max` of `Day`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

a %>% 
  mutate(Treatment = sub(" first day| last day", "", Treatment),
         Day = as.integer(Day)) %>% 
  group_by(Patient, Treatment) %>% 
  reframe(Day = min(Day):max(Day))

# A tibble: 12 × 3
   Patient Treatment   Day
   <chr>   <chr>     <int>
 1 1       A             3
 2 1       A             4
 3 1       A             5
 4 1       B            10
 5 1       B            11
 6 1       B            12
 7 1       B            13
 8 1       B            14
 9 2       A             2
10 2       A             3
11 2       A             4
12 2       A             5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `complete` combined with `fill`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a %>%
  separate(Treatment, into = c("Treatment", "first_last"), sep = " ", extra = "drop") %>% 
  group_by(Patient, Treatment) %>%
  mutate(Day = as.integer(Day)) %>% 
  complete(Day = seq(min(Day), max(Day))) %>%
  fill(Treatment, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  select(-first_last) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 12 × 3
   Patient Treatment   Day
   <chr>   <chr>     <int>
 1 1       A             3
 2 1       A             4
 3 1       A             5
 4 1       B            10
 5 1       B            11
 6 1       B            12
 7 1       B            13
 8 1       B            14
 9 2       A             2
10 2       A             3
11 2       A             4
12 2       A             5
```

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions! Kind regards